# Displaying image from tableWidget into PyQt5 form

Tags: mysql, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qpixmap, qbytearray

The image is already shown in the table widget column as an icon. I am now trying to exhibit a search function which will accept from a line edit such that the queried row data can be displayed through some labels. Kindly help review and modify this code in terms of best practice if my query format is vulnerable to SQL injection and assist in the correction so as for me to be able to display the image fetched from the database on the form. The code worked for displaying only text data but I didn't get the logic for redisplaying the image fetched from the tablewidget.

```
 def searchPers(self):
    con = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="", database="db")
    with con:
        cur = con.cursor()

        name = self.ui.name_edit.text()

        cmd = "SELECT * FROM persons WHERE name LIKE'"+name+"'"
        cur.execute(cmd)
        row = cur.fetchone()

        if row == None:
            self.ui.response_label.setText("Person not found")
        else:
            self.ui.name_label.setText(str(row[0]))
            pixmap = QPixmap()
            pixmap.loadFromData(QByteArray.toBase64(row[1]))
            self.ui.photo_label.setPixmap(QPixmap(pixmap))
```

Answer (score 0):

With several trial and errors I later got it:

```
def searchPers(self):
  con = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="", database="db")
  with con:
    cur = con.cursor()

    name = self.ui.name_edit.text()

    cmd = "SELECT * FROM persons WHERE name LIKE'"+name+"'"
    cur.execute(cmd)
    row = cur.fetchone()

    if row == None:
        self.ui.response_label.setText("Person not found")
    else:
        self.ui.name_label.setText(str(row[0]))
        pixmap = QPixmap()
        pixmap.loadFromData(QByteArray.fromBase64(row[1]))
        self.ui.photo_label.setPixmap(QPixmap(pixmap))
```